# Post to a closed group where Im admin

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I have the following code(facebook C# SDK) to post to facebook wall :

```
public long? UploadPost(string intLinkTitle, string inMessage, string inLinkCaption, string inLinkUrl, string inLinkDescription, string inLinkUrlPicture)
        {
            object obj;
            Facebook.JsonObject jsonObj;
            FacebookClient client;
            string access_token = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FacebookPageAccessToken"].ToString();

            client = new FacebookClient(access_token);

            var args = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            args["message"] = inMessage;
            args["caption"] = inLinkCaption;
            args["description"] = inLinkDescription;
            args["name"] = intLinkTitle;
            args["picture"] = inLinkUrlPicture;
            args["link"] = inLinkUrl;

            if ((obj = client.Post("/" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FacebookPageId"].ToString() + "/feed", args)) != null)
            {
                if ((jsonObj = obj as Facebook.JsonObject) != null)
                {
                    if (jsonObj.Count > 0)
                        return long.Parse(jsonObj[0].ToString().Split('_').Last().ToString());
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

This works great as long as I post to my public facebook website page but when changing the `FacebookPageId` to a group id instead I get `(FacebookApiException - #200) Permissions error`.

My user are admin of both the group and the page.

I have tried to post the message from the Graph API Explorer with the following line : `294632750660619/feed/?message=test` but there is a syntax problem here, have also tried `294632750660619/feed?message=test` but with no success.

How do I post to the closed facebook group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found the correct way. This is what I hade to do :

1. Go to the https://developers.facebook.com/ and create a new application
2. Settings > Add platform(Website and set the site URL(for example localhost..)
3. Set the app to go live(status & review > Yes), to do this a email adress needs to be set under settings > Contact Email
4. Go to the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname&version=v2.2)
5. Choose the new app from the dropdown
6. Click Get Access Token
7. Choose correct permissions(`user_groups`, `user_status`, `user_photos`, `manage_pages`, `publish_actions`, `read_insights` and `read_stream`) and click Get Access Token. Now we bot a short lived tooken
8. Generate a extended user token (valid for 60 days) by using this URL(change parameters(3)) : `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id=[app-id]&client_secret=[app-secret]&fb_exchange_token=[short-lived-token]`
9. Use the generated none expiring access token in the application
10. Validate the Access token here : `https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/access_token/`

Use this code to upload post :

```
public long? UploadPost(string intLinkTitle, string inMessage, string inLinkCaption, string inLinkUrl, string inLinkDescription, string inLinkUrlPicture)
        {
            object obj;
            Facebook.JsonObject jsonObj;
            FacebookClient client;
            string access_token = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FacebookPageAccessToken"].ToString();

            client = new FacebookClient(access_token);

            var args = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            args["message"] = inMessage;
            args["caption"] = inLinkCaption;
            args["description"] = inLinkDescription;
            args["name"] = intLinkTitle;
            args["picture"] = inLinkUrlPicture;
            args["link"] = inLinkUrl;

            if ((obj = client.Post("/" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FacebookPageId"].ToString() + "/feed", args)) != null)
            {
                if ((jsonObj = obj as Facebook.JsonObject) != null)
                {
                    if (jsonObj.Count > 0)
                        return long.Parse(jsonObj[0].ToString().Split('_').Last().ToString());
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
```

And to get feed, use this :

```
private void GetFeed()
        {
            object obj;
            Facebook.JsonObject jsonObj;
            Facebook.JsonObject jsonPaging;
            FacebookClient client;
            int pageCount = 0;
            string access_token;
            string URL;
            DateTime fetchFaceBookFeedFromDate;
            DateTime? oldestPostFetched = null;

            fetchFaceBookFeedFromDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30);
            access_token = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FacebookPageAccessToken"].ToString();
            URL = "/" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FacebookPageId"].ToString() + "/feed";

            client = new FacebookClient(access_token);


            while (URL.Length > 0 && pageCount < 1000)
            {
                if ((obj = client.Get(URL)) != null)
                {
                    if ((jsonObj = obj as Facebook.JsonObject) != null && jsonObj.Count > 0)
                    {
                        if (jsonObj[0] is Facebook.JsonArray)
                            oldestPostFetched = SaveFacebookForumThread(jsonObj[0] as Facebook.JsonArray, fetchFaceBookFeedFromDate);

                        if (jsonObj.Keys.Contains("paging") && (jsonPaging = jsonObj["paging"] as Facebook.JsonObject) != null && jsonPaging.Keys.Contains("next"))
                            URL = jsonPaging["next"].ToString();
                        else
                            break;
                    }
                }
                pageCount++;

                if (oldestPostFetched.HasValue && fetchFaceBookFeedFromDate > oldestPostFetched)
                    break;
            }
        }
```